# Mongodb multiple connections in mongoose /next js / in a single node/react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

We are using moongoose/MongoDb/Next js in our app and below is our sample server.js file, can you please help me in how to connect to multiple mongodb databases(mongoUrl and mongoUrl2) in this same file ? Appreciate any help!

Below is a code snippet

````
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const nextApp = next({ dev });
const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const username = process.env.MONGO_USERNAME;
const password = process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD;
const mongoEndpoint = process.env.MONGO_ENDPOINT;
const db = process.env.MONGO_DATABASE;
const mongoUrl = `mongodb://ourconnection`;
const mongoUrl2 = `need this db to connect`;

mongoose
  .connect(mongoUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...", err);
    process.exit();
  });

nextApp
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const expressApp = express();
    expressApp.use(bodyParser.json());
    require("./EVALUATION.routes.js")(expressApp);
    expressApp.get("*", (req, res) => {
      return nextHandler(req, res);
    });
    const server = expressApp.listen(3000, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("> Server started on http://localhost:3000");
    });

    const socketIo = require("socket.io");
    const io = socketIo(server);
    require("./sockets.js")(io);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Could not start the app. Exiting now...", err);
    process.exit();
  });```
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! According to the [`mongoose` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose#user-content-connecting-to-mongodb), `mongoose.createConnection` returns a connection, and you can execute this command several times for different connection URLs.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to show a code snippet on how to do it with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to separate the DB connection into another file to respect the single responsibility principle.

You can create a connection class, to accommodate the `createConnection` with multiple DBs

for example, we can create `connection.js`

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

function makeNewConnection(uri) {
    const db = mongoose.createConnection(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    db.on('error', function (error) {
        console.log(`MongoDB :: connection ${this.name} ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        db.close().catch(() => console.log(`MongoDB :: failed to close connection ${this.name}`));
    });

    db.on('connected', function () {
        mongoose.set('debug', function (col, method, query, doc) {
            console.log(`MongoDB :: ${this.conn.name} ${col}.${method}(${JSON.stringify(query)},${JSON.stringify(doc)})`);
        });
        console.log(`MongoDB :: connected ${this.name}`);
    });

    db.on('disconnected', function () {
        console.log(`MongoDB :: disconnected ${this.name}`);
    });

    return db;
}

const userConnection = makeNewConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/user');
const todoConnection = makeNewConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todo');

module.exports = {
    userConnection,
    todoConnection,
};
```

And then you can use it in your model class

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {userConnection, todoConnection} = require('./connections');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    isActive: Boolean,
}, {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true,
});

const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    completed: Boolean,
}, {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true,
});

const userModel = userConnection.model('User', userSchema);
const todoModel = todoConnection.model('Todo', todoSchema);

module.exports = {
    userModel,
    todoModel,
};
```

[reference](https://dev.to/ziishaned/open-multiple-mongodb-connection-in-express-js-app-36be)